# Image processing/color detection in R: what library should I use?

Tags: image, r, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I'm doing some image processing, and while I think I have a pretty good idea of my approach, I'm not having much luck finding which library(s) I should use to do this specifically in R.

I have a large database of similar images, each of which have an arbitrary number of variously-sized colored blobs on a white-ish background. I ultimately want to find the red, green, and blue values and calculate average RGB brightness across all colored pixels in all images from a particular date. This means being able to somehow differentiate colored pixels from near-white pixels and store their values.

I think what I want to do is create [color histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram) for a number of test images, look at the histograms' peaks to determine thresholds for what constitutes a "white" or "colored" pixel, then loop over the pixels in each image to find the colored ones matching my threshold(s) (I do know how to read in an image and get the pixel RGB values).

In my preferred language, Python, it sounds like I'd use the histogram method from the Image module in PIL, but I don't know the R equivalent (this may just be a weak point in my google-fu; search results are mostly for "R" as in "red" rather than the language. I did find this: [R: Histogram](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/hist.html), but I'm at a loss for whether it's relevant/how to use it).

If there might be a better approach from the domain of signal/image processing, I'd love to hear that, too.

**TL;DR: How can I make a color histogram of an image, or otherwise select pixels of certain color values, using R?**

(Related but not R-specific: [How to calculate the amount of "green spots" in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204256/how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-green-spots-in-an-image))

Comment: Perhaps rpy might help you out? http://rpy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @tkerwin - I wish, but I need to do this in pure R. If there's really no appropriate function in R I'll probably end up writing something in Python to determine the thresholds, and then hardcode that into my R script.

Comment: Why do you want to throw away all the information about the joint relationships?  I'd suggest you think about this as a 3d classification (or maybe clustering) problem.

Comment: @hadley - Would you mind explaining further? This isn't my area of expertise by a long shot, & I'm not sure what you mean by joint relationships in this context. I chose this approach because I'm primarily interested in color across all objects rather than characteristics of individual objects, and there's pretty clear distinctions between objects and background. It seemed more easily graspable than other computer-vision concepts, and I knew how to do it in Python. But I'd love it if you could suggest any resources for learning about 3d classification/clustering approaches.

Comment: Think about each pixel lying in a 3d space given by the values of R, G and B. For you data you'd expect to see two clusters - one for the background and one for the objects.  You want to find a simple rule to split them, but that rule might not be parallel to one of the axes.

Comment: @hadley - The 3D classification approach is what I ended up going with ... wish you had put that as an answer so I could accept it!

Answer (score 6):

There is also an R interface to ImageJ (which I used once in a distance past, it's excellent image classification software written in Java) via the [Bio7 package](http://129.70.40.49/modelling/?p=461).

Other links for more information:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/image-data-and-classification-with-r/

http://www.r-bloggers.com/plots-in-r-and-the-imagej-visualization/

http://www.r-bloggers.com/image-classification-limits-part-2/

Comment: That looks like a pretty neat piece of software that I didn't know about before! I've used ImageJ for similar things, but isn't that largely manual? I'm looking for command-line tools that can be run automatically over a pretty big image database.

Comment: Added some links, including one on memory limits when using it.  It's basically an interface between R and ImageJ, so it should let you automate things.

Comment: I've also found the [RImageJ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RImageJ/index.html) package on CRAN that directly provides bindings for ImageJ and R.

Comment: Bio7 link broken, and `RImageJ` was removed from the CRAN

Answer (score 4):

there is an excellent 'rimage' package on CRAN.

try this:

```
library(rimage)
x <- read.jpeg(system.file("data", "cat.jpg", package="rimage"))
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(x[,,1])
hist(x[,,2])
hist(x[,,3])
```

Comment: `> Package ‘rimage’ was removed from the CRAN repository.`